# Subclass of parse.com object in javascript properties after query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, subclass

I'm using parse.com as the backend to my project and am creating a web page using javascript.

I'm extending PFObject as follow:

```
var Match = Parse.Object.extend("Match");
```

On the match object i have a couple properties, let say the first one is "player1"

My question is how can i make it so that when i try to get a property of my match object it succeeds
ie:

```
var matchQuery = new Parse.Query("Match");
matchQuery.find({
    success: function (results) {
        _.each(results, function (element, index, list) {
            //
            var test = element.player1        <<<< here player1 is undefined
        })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Setting values on the backbone object works like regular JS.  The value is retained for as long as the object is in memory, but no longer.

```
match.memoryOnlyAttribute = "I'll be gone soon";
```

If match is released and then queried again, `memoryOnlyAttribute` will be null, as you have observed.

To get a value for a property that persists, it must first be a property on the object.  This is typically done in the data browser with the "+ Col" button.  (It can also be done in code if your CLP permits).

With that done, the object can only be assigned persistent property values via the `set()` method...

```
var Match = Parse.Object.extend("Match");
var match = new Match();
match.set("player1", /* an object here that is of the right type */);
match.save();
```

Once the object is retrieved, the property in the parse data can be retrieved with the `get()` method...

```
matchQuery.first().then(function(matchResult) {
    var player1 = match.get("player1");
    // player1 will have a value
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This does not solve my question though. The reason player1 is undefined is because if i want to get the value I have to call get("player1"). My question: "how can i make it so that the match object gets a property name player1 that essentialy calls get().